# Bash script to upload files

Tags: bash

I found this script online:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='your.ftp.site'
USER='remoteusername'
PASSWD='remotepasswd'

ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
ascii
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
//Stuff here
bye
EOT
```

[(Source)](https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/127-personal/386522)

What do I put in `//stuff here` to select the file `/serverfiles.zip` and put it on an external FTP server?

I've tried google, and while I feel this should be easy I can't find anything.

I'm on debian 7 x64

Answer (score 1):

```
mput /serverfiles.zip
```

should work.
From the *ftp* man page:

```
mput local-files
     Expand wild cards in the list of local files given as argu-
     ments and do a put for each file in the resulting list.  See
     glob for details of filename expansion.  Resulting file names
     will then be processed according to ntrans and nmap settings.
```